# Does @DataJpaTest configures correctly "updatable = false" in tests when using H2 database?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa

I'm asking this because even using the @Column notation over the attribute with the value "updatable = false", it still passing in the test I update it.

```
@Column(length = 100, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String exampleId;
```

I'm using H2 database and @DataJpaTest.  Tests are functioning correctly except by this one.

I'm testing it:

```
@Test
public void ExampleRepository_Update_ChangingExampleExampleId(){

    ExampleRepository.save(example);

    Example savedExample = exampleRepository.getById(example.getId());

    savedExample.setExampleId("7");
    Example updatedExample = ExampleRepository.save(savedExample);

    assertEquals("7", updatedExample.getExampleId());
}
```

But it shouldn't be able to update it, but it is.

I know the test isn't right because it's testing a scenario that it would be possible, but the problem is why it is passing if it shouldn't.

Comment: Your test is wrong and doesn't test what you think it tests. You should check the database not the JPA entity as that is what you changed yourself. The database will remain unchanged. Which is what you should check, after the save and a flush of the entitymanager, with a separate query bypassing JPA.